# @Html.ValidationMessageFor() custom validationMessage always shown

Tags: forms, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to use a different message for `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` in ASP.NET MVC3. This works fine but it seems to make the message be always displayed , e.g. if I do this:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TimesheetEntry.Product)
```

then the error is only shown when I submit the form and it is invalid. However if I do this:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TimesheetEntry.Product, "custom error")
```

then that message is displayed as soon as I initially load the page. I'm probably doing something stupid here and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Have you tried the CSS from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370131/asp-net-mvc-3-rc-razor-validationmessagefor-custommessage-and-clientsidevalidat)?

```
.field-validation-valid
{
    display: none;
}
.validation-summary-valid
{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks - done that now and it works. It just seems a bit of a hack though

Comment: @Tom Haigh I think this CSS is added out of the box with a new MVC3 web application. The answer I referenced suggests the CSS was removed sometime during development.

Comment: Why do I have to add these classes manually? I thought MVC would add it automatically. Anyways, the solution works perfectly.

Comment: @Jesus--MVC version 3 does add these classes by default. The OP of the question I linked to above mentions these accidentally being removed at some point in their workflow

Comment: @David I know this is a dated post, but I'm using MVC 5 and using an Ajax.BeginForm. I put this css in and it hides them, but once a click submit, the validations don't show up. Any recommendations (or should I start  new post)?

Comment: @ajtatum probably start a new post so we can see some code. id start digging into your success callback--maybe it's doing something funky

Answer (score 8):

probably you have model parameter in your **httpGet** ActionResult method

Answer (score 7):

I also had this problem and did the "hack" from above by adding the two css-classes with display none. I then discovered that if I moved my error-message to my model and used empty string as parameter in ValidationMessageFor everything solved out and I was able to delete the two classes.

In model

```
 [Display(Name = "Caption"), Required(ErrorMessage = "Caption is required")]
```

In cshtml

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.caption, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.caption, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Comment: This is the answer that enabled me to use Bootstrap styling with the validation message. +1, thanks.

Comment: I agree - its easier to define it from the model instead. Also; if you want language support the model is definitely the way to do it with a resource definition.

Comment: @Christian and in case of multilanguage how can I do ?

Comment: @Kris-I Your model knows the language, correct? An example can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23780943/how-to-create-custom-validation-attribute

Answer (score 2):

I have not played with validation enough in MVC 3, so I am just running through the way I would troubleshoot this issue.

I would look at this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470929.aspx

Yeah, standard MSDN documentation, but the ValidationMessageFor() method states:

*Returns the HTML markup for a validation-error message for each data field that is represented by the specified expression, using the specified message.*

That sounds, to me, like it should always return the message, even when you are not supplying a custom message as a string. It looks like there are other methods that may better fit your need on the URI specified.

Comment: yeah thanks that's interesting. It's strange though that the overload that doesn't take a custom message behaves differently though (and doesn't always show the message), even though the description on that page is similar

Comment: I dont know why anyone would ever look anything up in MSDN anymore. Its crazy overly explained in details no one needs, impossible to be sure you get the right info (Wall of Text) and examples (if any) are unusable in RL Hello Worlds. Your answer just proofs you too thought you had the right info, but in fact didn't.
There are like seven overloads on ValidationMessageFor in MVC/Razor - with ValidationMessage desc: 
The message to display if the specified field contains an error or The message to display if a validation error occurs. I'm sorry; I'm not trying to put you down. Just MSDN.