# How to create custom validation attribute?

Tags: c#, data-annotations

I am trying to create a custom validation attribute.

```
public class PhoneValidator : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return new RegularExpressionAttribute(@"^[+0]\d+").IsValid(Convert.ToString(value).Trim());
    }
}
```

And I use this to use

```
[PhoneValidator]
public string PhoneNumber { get; private set; }
```

I copied it from a website, in theory this should work. But I couldn't make it work.

Comment: *in theory this functions but I do not to function* What? What's not working? How are you invoking validation?

Comment: I like to mark in red the field during I am typing the text not after, do you remember me?

Comment: Have you read this?http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668224%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: I am reading now, thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here is example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668224%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

**PhoneMaskAttribute .cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;


[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
sealed public class PhoneMaskAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    // Internal field to hold the mask value.
    readonly string _mask;

    public string Mask
    {
        get { return _mask; }
    }

    public PhoneMaskAttribute(string mask)
    {
        _mask = mask;
    }


    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var phoneNumber = (String)value;
        bool result = true;
        if (this.Mask != null)
        {
            result = MatchesMask(this.Mask, phoneNumber);
        }
        return result;
    }

    // Checks if the entered phone number matches the mask.
    internal bool MatchesMask(string mask, string phoneNumber)
    {
        if (mask.Length != phoneNumber.Trim().Length)
        {
            // Length mismatch.
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < mask.Length; i++)
        {
            if (mask[i] == 'd' && char.IsDigit(phoneNumber[i]) == false)
            {
                // Digit expected at this position.
                return false;
            }
            if (mask[i] == '-' && phoneNumber[i] != '-')
            {
                // Spacing character expected at this position.
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
          ErrorMessageString, name, this.Mask);
    }

}
```

**Usage:**

**CustomerMetadata.cs:**

```
using System.Web.DynamicData;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
[MetadataType(typeof(CustomerMetadata))]
public partial class Customer
{
}
public class CustomerMetadata
{
    [PhoneMask("999-999-9999",
        ErrorMessage = "{0} value does not match the mask {1}.")]
    public object Phone; 
}
```

Links:

[How to: Customize Data Field Validation in the Data Model Using Custom Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668224%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: But this functions after or before to click in button? I Try the example of Microsoft and this do not show during the input the text

Comment: Your question is "How to create custom validation attribute?", right?

Comment: If you want to get answer on another question, like "How to make client side validation on keypress", etc, then please create separate question.

Comment: This article can help you with client side validation: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/javascript/creating-a-mvc-3-application-with-razor-and-unobtrusive-javascript

Comment: How to add it to swagger document?

Answer (score 5):

1-create a `class` for this

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public class MobileValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public MobileValidationAttribute(string errorMessage)
        {
            ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
        }

        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            if (value == null) return false;
            return value.ToString().Length == 13;
        }
    }
```

2-create a `model`

```
    public class UserModel
    {
        [Display(Name ="Phone Number")]
        [MobileValidation("{0} is invalid")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings =false,ErrorMessage ="{0} is required")]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

3- in view use this code

```
@model TestAttribute.Models.UserModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        <form method="post" action="/Home/Index">
            @Html.LabelFor(a=>a.PhoneNumber)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(a=>a.PhoneNumber)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a=>a.PhoneNumber)

            <br />
            <br />

            <button type="submit">Add</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

4- and `Controller`

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(new UserModel());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(UserModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Content("Ok");
            }
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```