# Getting ValidationError from TypeConverter in a form

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have class `Phone` that I am using in a class `Entity`. I wrote a converter from `Phone/string` in order to use the `Phone` directly in a form.

When I enter a valid phone number the code works fine. When I enter an invalid phone number the exception is correctly thrown from the converter. But I am not able to get the exception and display it as a validation error in the blazor UI.

I tried almost everything I can think of in the Blazor component with `editcontext` and `model` but I was not able to display the error thrown from the converter.

Minimum reproducible would be:

index.razor:

```
@page "/"

<EditForm Model="m" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="phone">Phone</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="phone" @bind="@m.Phone" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => m.Phone)" />
    </div>

</EditForm>

@code
{
    Entity m = new();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        m.Phone = new Phone("");
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    private void HandleValidSubmit()
    {

    }
}
```

Entity:

```
  public class Entity
  {
      public Phone Phone { get; set; }
  }


  [TypeConverter(typeof(PhoneConverter))]
  public class Phone
  {
      public string Number { get; }

      public Phone(string number)
      {   
          //imagine some real validation here...
          if(number.StartsWith("123"))
          {
              throw new ArgumentException("invalid phone number.");
          }
          Number = number;
      }

      public override string ToString() => Number;

   }


    public class PhoneConverter : TypeConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext? context, Type sourceType)
        {
            return sourceType == typeof(string) || base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
        }

        public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext? context, Type? destinationType)
        {
            return destinationType == typeof(string) || base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
        }

        public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext? context, CultureInfo? culture, object value)
        {
            if (value is string strValue)
            {
                try
                {
                    return new Phone(strValue);
                }
                catch (ArgumentException ex)
                {
                    //gets thrown correctly
                    throw new ValidationException(ex.Message);
                }
            }

            return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value)!;
        }

        public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext? context, CultureInfo? culture, object? value, Type destinationType)
        {
            if (destinationType == typeof(string) && value is Phone number)
            {
                return number.ToString();
            }

            return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType)!;
        }
    }
```

When I enter `123` to trigger the validation error. The error get's thrown but all that happens is that the textbox get's reset.
What I want is the value `123` is still in the textbox and the validation error is shown or only the validation error is shown.

Comment: It seems very odd to be doing validation in a TypeConverter. Validation should happen _before_ attempting to write to the database, not _during_ the attempt. Have a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23781686/2363967)